# How do I calculate kg/m for 5 boards sitting on 3 beams

Tags: beam

I'm new to this, thank you for your patience,

I have some wooden boards that each weigh 5.5 kg with dimensions of 120 cm * 60 cm
I also have some wooden beams with dimensions of 3 meters length and 10 cm width (and 3 cm thickness)

[image]

I want to know the "kgf/m" along the beam.

I looked around a bit and came to this conclusion, but I'm unsure if it's correct or not.

This is for **config A**

```
board_weight     = 5.5 # kg
beam_length      = 3   # meter
number_of_boards = 5
number_of_beams  = 3

weight_of_all_boards = board_weight * number_of_boards

kgf_per_meter = (weight_of_all_boards / beam_length) / number_of_beams

kgf_per_meter  # 3.0554
```

So the kilogram force per meter is `3.0554` (on each beam)

Or in the case of **config B** is `2.291665`

Is this correct?

## Edit #1:

I then go to "SkyCiv" online app and try to make a sfbm diagram like the following.

[image]
[image]

## Edit #2:

I thought if I explain how I came to the conclusion, it would be easier to answer.

All 5 boards together weigh `27.5 kg`, so I first said to myself let's pretend they are a huge brick.
[image]

Then I thought let's first imagine its weight on a single beam.
Now I have a `27.5 kg` distributed load on a single beam.

My problem is I don't know how to calculate `kgf/m` in this setup.
I have a `3 meter` beam.
I have a huge `27.5 kg` break laying on top of it.
Should I divide weight of the brick by length of beam?
`27.5 / 3` which is `9.1667`

Because that's what I did.
And then I divided to 3 because I thought whatever the force is on 1 beam, then when there's 3 of them, it should be divided between them.

And I ended up with `3.0554`
[image]

Comment: In a simplified process in buildings, the tributary load area for a situation like this would be to take half the distance to the next beam.  Depending on how much overhang there is for the outside beam you may find that the outside beam carries less for small to no over hang, and more for large over hang.  A more refined breakdown would be your edit 1.  However, for your edit 1, there appears to be no overhang.